# How can I limit USB2.0 transfer rate on linux?

Tags: linux, usb, throttling

I have a simple project which can limit USB2.0 transfer rate on linux. With this program users can select any transfer speed they want, let say 10 Mbps. But I don't know where to start or what to do. I will be very glad if you have any idea. An useful library or function or whatever. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit GLOBAL USB2.0 rate on the whole system, then you must probably write a Linux Kernel module. Learning kernel programming is very hard and not something that is considered a "simple project".

If you want to do it for a simple application then just put some timers in the program that "throtte" data writing/reading according to user selection. Notice that this code has to be in the application itself.